# Django 1.4 serving MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL files on development server

Tags: django

Just upgraded to Django 1.4, and having serious trouble with the new 'improved' serving of static and media files on development server. I love Django, but why on earth they have made serving these files doubly more complicated with STATIC_URL,STATIC_ROOT, STATICFILES_DIR now is utterly beyond me.

I'm simply trying to serve all files, static and uploaded, on the development server. I have the STATIC_URL files working, after much experimentation, but I simply cannot get the MEDIA_URL files to be served as well.

Settings:

```
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
```

I've got the media and static context processors added:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.core.context_processors.static',
"django.core.context_processors.request",
'satchmo_store.shop.context_processors.settings',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
```

)

and I've added in the url confs:

```
# serve static and uploaded files in DEV
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

with the two conf settings added as indicated in the docs, first one for static, second for media.

my structure, website being an app and static dir placed inside it as instructed on djangoproject:

```
<myproject>
  --media
  --settings
  --templates
  --website
      |->static
```

In templates I can serve static content no problem with

```
{{STATIC_URL}}css/style.css
```

But any uploaded image, this one using photologue, is not served, but the urls are correct:

```
/media/photologue/photos/cache/spawning-2_admin_thumbnail.jpg
```

That directory structure does exit under media/

Super, super confused. It all seems so ridiculously complicated now, whereas I never had any issues before.

Comment: I know that feel, I just gave up and used mod_wsgi and Apache to circumvent Django's whole way of doing it.

Comment: I should add I've got the staticfiles app installed and DEBUG = True, because I can serve static files..

Comment: should it be `urlpatterns += static(...` not just plus?

Comment: changed it to the old way, as per @username below:urlpatterns += (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', 
   {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
) but still no joy.

Answer (score 2):

I´m very new to Django and I´ve never had any problem with static content.

This is my configuration. I hope it can help

**My folder structure**

```
django-project
--mainapp
----settings.py
----wsgi.py
----[...]
--otherapp
--fixtures
--static
--templates
--manage.py
--requirements.txt
```

**settings.py**

```
import os, socket

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
MAIN_APP = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(MAIN_APP, ".."))
MY_LOCALHOST = "VirusVault.local" # this is the real name of my local machine :)

try: HOST_NAME = socket.gethostname()
except: HOST_NAME = "localhost"
```

[...]

```
if HOST_NAME == MY_LOCALHOST:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')
    STATIC_URL = "/static/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'media/')
    MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = "/server/path/to/static/files"
    STATIC_URL = "http://server.com/static/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = "/server/path/to/static/files/media/"
    MEDIA_URL = 'http://server.com/static/media/'
```

You need to add `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` to INSTALLED_APPS

**urls.py**

```
if settings.HOST_NAME == settings.MY_LOCALHOST:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

Comment: I forgot to say this configuration is valid for my production server at Webfaction. That´s why I included "if" confitional, so I just need one settings file for both development and production enviroments

Comment: I think, using Django's server to serve static files on a production server is a terrible choice. It is just for development purposes. Better use mod_wsgi with Apache or Nginx and serve static files over it. Also you don't need that absolute url definitions.

Comment: Hi @username. I don´t use django server for production. This configuration is working in apache (mod_wsgi) and nginx for static files. Everything beyond /static/ is handled by nginx. The absolute url was just for clarity

Answer (score 0):

I intended to write a comment first but somehow `add comment` button doesn't work.

Did you check the permissions of media directory?

Since it became an answer, I am going to dump one of my perfectly working Django 1.4 sites configuration.

structure:

```
-myproject
-- media
-- static
-- templates
-- myproject
--- settings.py
--- urls.py
```

settings.py:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)) # Not the best way but works
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', 
   {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: How does that work though - you don't have a url conf setting for serving the files under '/media'? How does the server know what to do with those files?

Comment: @user1907157 It boils down to username using PROJECT_ROOT instead of DIRNAME to set MEDIA_ROOT. Settings.py is now in a sub-folder of project root and media root needs to be updated accordingly. See my answer.

Comment: @Enrico. You're right. And my `PROJECT_ROOT` is as silly as this: `PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Comment: @username In Django 1.4 settings.py should be in the project app folder, not the project root. (via [Django 1.4 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py))

Comment: @Enrico My settings.py is not in the project root. Look at the structure. That's why I call `os.path.dirname` twice. Now i edited my post to reduce the ambiguity.

Comment: Clever, I didn't pick up on that the first time.

Comment: surely I shouldn't have to move settings.py, how would that even work? I can upload a photo from admin no problem, and it does go into the folders under /media correctly. Doesn't this mean that MEDIA_ROOT is correct?

Comment: OK, I've got it working guys, but I don't know why. It's something to do with Satchmo. Once I disabled those apps, works like a charm with my exact settings above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django 1.4 folder structure, you've moved `settings.py` to your new `website` app folder which means your MEDIA_ROOT is now incorrect. Not sure if a relative location works in this case, but it should be something like this

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DIRNAME, '../media/')
```

It might be simpler to use an absolute path.

Comment: Nope, haven't moved settings.py into website app - it's in the <myproject> app as set by startproject command. Should it be in website app?

Comment: It should be in myproject/myproject; that's where Django 1.4 puts it in new projects. I thought website was your "myproject" app, my apologies. The answer still holds. Does using an absolute path work?

Comment: I'm sure you're on the right lines @Enrico. using absolute path doesn't work either at the moment though.