# Why is django not serving my media files?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

In my `settings.py`,

```
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
#STATICFILES_DIRS =
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'media')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/
```

in my template,

```
     <div class=" event_image">
      <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ restaurant.logo }}" /> 
     </div>
```

This doesnot work in development, it returns a 404 `"GET /media/restaurant_detail/restaurant_detail/information_about_object.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 178672`

what am i doing wrong,what is the right way to go about it so it works in both in dev't and production. i looked here ([Django 1.4 serving MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL files on development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897982/django-1-4-serving-media-url-and-static-url-files-on-development-server)) but all in vain.

Comment: Did you do `python manage.py collectstatic`? Try to find this file in file system manually.

Comment: have you set your main urls.py for media and static?

Comment: yeah i did but i figured out the problem,kept looking around, now just fixed it..let me `Edit` the question..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081893/unable-to-serve-static-files-like-css-js-in-django-python/15082062#15082062

Comment: @catherine thats what i had to do to fix it...let me edit my question

Comment: can you post also the structure of your project

Comment: yes am going to do that in the edit

Comment: @catherine uhhmm, i just edited the question with what works,so do u think its clean.. its working but is it clean enough.

Comment: instead of editing your question with the answer, you can post the portion of your edit that fixed the problem as it's own answer and accept that so the question is seen as being solved

Comment: Just an fyi but the Django docs highly discourage using django to serve media files in production because it is inefficient and potentially insecure.  You can see the warning they have a little way down the page here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development

Comment: @joshcartme this was not in production, its was in development but thanks for pointing that out anyway...

Comment: @SuziemacTani gotcha, I was a little confused because you said you wanted to get it working in dev't and production, but I think I understand now!

Answer (score 4):

Turns out i had to include the urls,my urls

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

)
```

The above worked..

```
my project structure
-myproject
-- media
-- static
-- templates
-- settings.py
-- manage.py
-- app
```

Answer (score 0):

Suziemac, It worked for me too. Here is a link for original documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/views/ . 
When I was developing an app I have used `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT),` however this did not work when I deployed an app.